# Return [[PromiseResult]] in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

[image: [[Promise=]]]

How to return [[PromiseResult]] guys, please help thankss
i use vue js and laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that result by adding `then` method to the Promise. For example:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('success')).then(res => console.log(res))
```

This code will log your [[PromiseResult]] object.